# MQCONNX FAILED WITH mqrc 2393 ssl initialization error

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

I tried to use amqsslc sample program on MQ but it’s failing with MQCONNX FAILED WITH mqrc 2393 ssl initialization error

MQ version is 9
Cipher spec used is TLS 1.2 AES 256 SHA 256

JRE version : IBM : version 8

```
./amqssslc -m TEST -c TEST.ASL -x 'localhost(4540)' -k "/var/mqm/qmgrs/TEST/ssl/key" -s TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

Comment: `amqsslc` is not a java program so the JRE version would not make a difference. Can you please provide the full command you ran?  Click edit and update your question with the full `amqsslc` command with all options.

Comment: Hello Josh 
Thanks for the comments

Comment: Even the amqsputc fails with the same reason , exported the MQSERVER variable also

Comment: Look at `/var/mqm/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` for a error entry with a timestamp matching when you receive the 2393, also look at the queue managers log `/var/mqm/qmgrs/TEST/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` for a error matching the timestamp.  Add them to the question if possible.  Note you can put `\`\`\`` above and below something you want to show up in fixed with font like those error log entries.

Comment: AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel TEST.ASL

Comment: If that is from the client side, what does the qmgr say?  the other end of the connection (the queue manager) will log a error `AMQ9631: The CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake does not match the required CipherSpec for channel`, this error will have details of what the queue manager expected and what was sent.  But basically it means that the queue manager is not expecting `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`.

Comment: I am using the mq client on the same machine where queue manager is hosted . The error amq9641 is logged in /var/mqm/errors.there is nothing reported in queue manager logs

Comment: There should be a error on the queue manager side that matches.  If you don't see one check your port is really being listened to by that queue manager.  You can do `ps -ef|grep TEST|grep lsr` and look at the options on the `runmqlsr` process and make sure you see port `4540`.

Comment: Queue Manager is listening to the correct port no since the non ssl channels are  up and running

Comment: Try this command to see what the output is for comparison: `amqscnxc -c TEST.ASL -x 'localhost(4540)'`, it should act like `amqsslc` but will make a non-TLS connection.

Comment: it fails with the same reason
mqrc 2393

Comment: I reproduced what I would expect the behavior to be, first I ran `amqscnxc -c TEST.CHL -x 'localhost(xxxx)'`, the `/var/mqm/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` error was `AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel 'TEST.CHL' to host 'xxx (x.x.x.x)(xxxx)'.` and the queue manager `AMQERR01.LOG`error was `AMQ9639: Remote channel 'TEST.CHL' did not specify a CipherSpec.`.

Comment: Second I ran `amqssslc -c TEST.CHL -x 'localhost(xxxx)' -k key -s TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`, the `/var/mqm/errors/AMQERR01.LOG` error was `AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel 'TEST.CHL' to host 'xxx (x.x.x.x)(xxxx)'.` and the queue manager `AMQERR01.LOG`error was `AMQ9631: The CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake does not match the required CipherSpec for channel 'TEST.CHL'.`

Comment: Can you please recheck your queue manger's `AMQERR01.LOG` file?  Can you possibly post the full `AMQ9631` error you see in the `/var/mqm/errors/AMQERR01.LOG`.  Another test that will produce a error in the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG is `amqscnxc -c BOGUS -x 'localhost(xxxx)' where BOGUS is a "channel name" that does not exist on the queue manager, the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG will produce a `AMQ9519: Channel BOGUS' not found.` error.  If you don't see these errors then please check that the queue manager is actually listening on `localhost(4540)`.

Comment: If you are on linux (or a unix that has `lsof` installed) you can confirm which process is listening on the port by running `lsof -nPi:4540`.  The output will have a line with `*:4540 (LISTEN)` on the right it may also have a specific IP like `x.x.x.x:4540 (LISTEN)` which would indicate it only listens on that interface.  The second column on he left side is the PID number, run something like `ps -ef | grep <PID from lsof output>`, this will show you the process that is listening such as `/opt/mqm/bin/runmqlsr -r -m TEST -t TCP -p 4540`, the name after the `-m` is the queue manager name.